# defining variable to a structure

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, structure, dynamic-memory-allocation

Following is the part of a code which wrote for making a linked list

```
struct node
{  int data;
 struct node *link;
}*head;
```

In the above source code, I want to ask that whether head is a variable of "**node**"  or not. I think that as I declared it with structure so it must be a variable to the defined structure & thus contain a data part & a address part.
If I am wrong can anyone please tell me what is the role of *head & is it a variable or not ?

Now , this is the second part of the same source code

```
void addbeg()
 {
 int d,g;
 struct node *temp;
 temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
 }
```

Here `void addbeg` is a function, now here we declared another variable to `struct node`, then why are we allocating it memory equal to a `int`, as it is a variable to struct node, so it must contain size of a pointer & a `int`. But why are still allocating it memory. Please clear this doubt also.

Comment: Well please tell us, why *are* you allocating memory for a single `struct`? To the first question, `*head` is a *pointer* to `struct node`.

Comment: Oh, wow, you must study pointers and memory management in C first (as well as `struct`s declaration), otherwise any answer would be ridiculously huge.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to explain your questions in brief, but to solve your confusion, @ForceBru's comment is the right idea.

1. The usage of `struct` in `C`, defining variable right after the definition of a `struct` is a short cut to do those two steps separately, namely it equals to `define the struct` + `struct node *head` (define a variable pointing to a struct node / a pointer to node).
2. `temp` as a pointer to a struct node is similar to variable `node`, except that it's now pointing to a real struct node that have been just allocated in memory space (using `malloc`). It's similar to the following code, but differ in whether the compiler or yourself should manage the memory allocated (due to dynamic memory allocation).

   ```
   // define a struct node that's allocated and managed by the compiler
   struct node nodeOfTemp;
   struct node *temp = &nodeOfTemp;
   ```

Comment: please consider the following code struct student                                                    struct student
{
    char name[50];
    int roll;
    float marks;
} s1;                                                                                                                  Here s1 is a variable to above structure of student & will have all parts of structure & not any address, how come in the above case of struct node, * head is a pointer.